# Reduce width and height of any element of a certain class with CSS

Tags: css

It there a way to reduce the width and height of an element based on its CSS class by a fixed number. So for example if I have a div, and I apply a class to it, can I reduce the width by x and height by x? i.e.:

```
.slight-reduction {
    width: previousWidth - 2px;
    height: previousHeight -2px;
}
```

Is it possible to do this in CSS? How do you do it if it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite what you are asking for but sort of. You can use `calc();` function in CSS to accomplish, perhaps what you want.

```
div {
    height:calc(100% - 300px);
}
```

It's not possible to obtain any previous width as you show in your question using CSS and the second value must be a unit of some kind, such as px.

Note the spacing before and after the subtraction operator. That needs to be there.

[Further info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)